# AWS sqs send message batch from cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cli

I am trying to send a batch of messages from the command line using aws cli. The command looks like this:

```
aws sqs send-message-batch \
    --queue-url https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/... \
    --region=us-west-2 \
    --cli-input-json "[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"MessageBody\":\"[344ED079FC85292446B193170E02F6C51882A761]\"},{\"Id\":\"2\",\"MessageBody\":\"[B584291B654587C7C957E10DF8B50FB31B2F589E]\"}]"
```

The problem is it returns an error code 255:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I've never been lucky using the cli-input-json. save your messages as Json file and reference this file as `--entries file://path/to/file.json

Comment: Yeah, thought about that. The problem is I have 10k messages to send, and creating a file for each 10 batch is an ugly solution :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close!
The cli help is kind of vague about this, but the argument for the `--entries` parameter can be provided with either JSON or shorthand syntax directly (without cli-input-json). So your command should look like:

```
aws sqs send-message-batch \
    --queue-url https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/... \
    --region=us-west-2 \
    --entries "[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"MessageBody\":\"[344ED079FC85292446B193170E02F6C51882A761]\"},{\"Id\":\"2\",\"MessageBody\":\"[B584291B654587C7C957E10DF8B50FB31B2F589E]\"}]"
```

The `--cli-input-json` parameter is an optional parameter available on all cli commands that allows you to provide all arguments (not individual) for a command as json.  It is unecessary in this case